# If/else for conditional <select> option

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I am having troubling getting a simply if/else conditional for options in an html select form. If the value for bid is 'N', then I want one option for the select field to change to "Y" and vice versa. I know my db connection is good and other php works and the form was updating the db fine until I tried to work in the php conditional code within the  so I just need to get the syntax correct.

```
 /* fetch associative array */
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
 ?>

 <form method="post" name="update" action="update.php" >
 <select name="bid">

 <option value="<?php echo $row['bid']; ?>" selected="selected">
 <?php echo $row['bid']; ?></option>

 <? if ($row['bid'] == 'N') {  
 ?>

 <option value="Y">Y</option>

 <?   } else {

 ?>

 <option value="N">N</option>

 <? }
 ?>

</select>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="update" > 
</form>

<?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if` statement expect expression and you have syntax error in your statement

```
if (echo $row['bid']; == 'N')
```

the syntax error because of `echo` and the semicolon `;`

you should change your condition to

```
if ($row['bid'] == 'N'){
```

if `$row['bid']` string then you need to compare with `strcmp` , like this

```
if (strcmp($row['bid'] , 'N') == 0){
```

also you need to move `<input>` tag outside the `<select>`

Comment: That did it. Thanks to the rest who offered solutions I didn't get to yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<input type="submit">` was inside your `<select>`, so I moved it outside.

It is also incorrect to use the `if` statement in this manner:

```
if (echo $row['bid']; == 'N')
```

correct would be this:

```
if ($row['bid'] == 'N')
```

**Here is the corrected code:**

```
<form method="post" name="update" action="update.php" >
<select name="bid">

<?php
echo '<option value="'.$row['bid'].'" selected="selected">'.$row['bid'].'</option>';

if ($row['bid'] == 'N') echo '<option value="Y">Y</option>';
else echo '<option value="N">N</option>';

echo '</select>';
?>

<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="update" >
</form>
```

Comment: I like the idea but getting HTTP 500 error. Something is off.

Comment: When do you get the error, on submit or on page load?

Comment: @JA4677 I think your problem is that you are using short tags in `PHP` like this `<?   ?>` instead of the full and proper way `<?php   ?>`. The `<?   ?>` can get mistaken for xml.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is bad, you must remove `echo` and `;`. it should like this

```
<? if ($row['bid'] == 'N') { ?>
```

And your submit button should be presented out side the select field.
Your codes should look like this:

```
<form method="post" name="update" action="update.php" >
    <select name="bid">

       <option value="<?=$row['bid']?>" selected="selected">
           <?=$row['bid']?>
       </option>

      <?php if ($row['bid'] == 'N') { 
          echo '<option value="Y">Y</option>';
      } else {
          echo '<option value="N">N</option>';
      }
      ?>

     </select>
     <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="update" > 
 </form>
```

Answer (score -2):

Your if condition has bad syntax. Remove the semicolon and echo statement.

```
<form method="post" name="update" action="update.php" >
 <select name="bid">

 <option value="<?php echo $row['bid']; ?>" selected="selected">
 <?php echo $row['bid']; ?></option>

 <? if ($row['bid'] == 'N') {  
 ?>

 <option value="Y">Y</option>

 <?   } else {

 ?>

 <option value="N">N</option>

 <? }
 ?>

 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="update" >

 </select> 
 </form>
```